# django cannot create a regular object in a view, returns 500 error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, view

I'm having a problem with a ajax request in a django project. I have tried to debug the view code by add print statements everywhere until I found where it just seems to stop and return a 500 error. I don't know why this is happening so I was hoping someone with a bit more experience would know what is going wrong.

The javascript libraries I'm using are jQuery (only for the ajax call though) and GogoMakePlay (GogoMakePlay.com)

The application is a browser based chess game with a backend in django and javascript (GogoMakePlay) for displaying the chess board. In this situation the chess board is displayed and when I click on a piece it is supposed to make an ajax call to a django view which returns a json of the possible moves. I click on a pawn piece every time so that my print functions are executed and I should have been able to find the problem but not this time.

My problem is pretty much the same as this one:

[Cannot create new Django model object within Ajax post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537399/cannot-create-new-django-model-object-within-ajax-post-request)

except unlike him, my problem did not just disappear.

the view in question:

```
def get_move_options(request):
  if request.POST:
    # initialise some variables based on the request type
    pieceType = request.POST.get("pieceType")
    pieceColour = request.POST.get("pieceColour")
    pieceRow = request.POST.get("row")
    pieceColumn = request.POST.get("column")
    gameId = request.POST.get("gameId")
    game = Game.objects.get(pk=gameId)
    moves = Move.objects.filter(game=game)
    print "initialised all the variables"

    # check what type of piece it is
    if pieceType == "pawn":
        print "colour:" + pieceColour
        piece = Pawn(pieceColour)
        print "created the piece: " + piece # <-- this is never executed                                           
    elif pieceType == "king":
        piece = King(pieceColour)
    elif pieceType == "queen":
        piece = Queen(pieceColour)
    elif pieceType == "bishop":
        piece = Bishop(pieceColour)
    elif pieceType == "knight":
        piece = Knight(pieceColour)
    elif pieceType == "rook":
        piece = Rook(pieceColour)
    print "created the piece: " + piece
    # make a new board and apply the moves to it
    board = Board()
    for move in moves:
        board.makeMove(move)
    print "made all the moves"

    # get the possible moves
    responseList = piece.getMoveOptions(pieceColumn, pieceRow, board)

  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseList), mimetype="application/javascript")
```

the Pawn code:

```
 class Pawn(Piece):
   def __init__(self, colour):
     print "creating object"
     self.colour = colour
     print "object created, the colour is: " + colour
 *snip*
```

the ajax request code:

```
*snip*
// get the csrf_token from the page TODO there must be a better way of doing this
var csrf_token = document.getElementById("csrf_token").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

// add the variables to the post data
var data = {
        "gameId" : gameId,
    "pieceType" : piece.S.type,
    "pieceColour" : piece.S.colour,
    "column" : column,
    "row" : row,
    };
var url = "ajax/getMoveOptions";
// make the ajax call
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        // add the csrf_token or we will get a 403 response
    headers : {
    "X-CSRFToken" : csrf_token
    },
    url : url,
    data : data,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(json) {
    // loop through the json list
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        // change the square colour of the options
    var x = json[i]["row"];
    var y = json[i]["column"];
    var option = G.O["square" + y + x];
    if(y % 2 == x % 2) {
            var squareColour = "white";
    } else {
        var squareColour = "black";
    }
    option.setSrc("/static/images/board/" + squareColour + "Option.png").draw();
    }
},
error : alert("I have now seen this too many times"),
});
*snip*
```

my django console output:

```
 *snip*
 [01/Jun/2012 02:07:45] "GET /static/images/chess_pieces/white/king.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1489
 initialised all the variables
 colour:white
 creating object
 object created, the colour is: white
 [01/Jun/2012 02:07:48] "POST /game/ajax/getMoveOptions HTTP/1.1" 500 10331
```

I know that I could just write the code in the javascript instead, but this is a school project and one of my goals was to understand how to make ajax calls.

I have been googling this for hours and found only the aforementioned link that relates to my problem. Usually StackOverflow has ALL the answers, but in this case I have been forced to create an account so that I can ask this question. Please forgive me if there is a similar question with a solution to my problem.

So my questions are:

1. Do you require more information to help me? If so what do you need to know?
2. Is my ajax call correct?
3. If so, why is it giving a 500 error? If not, then what am I doing wrong?
4. Why does the view start executing but stop immediately after the Pawn object has been created?

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint for this line: piece = Pawn(pieceColour) and check do you have any exceptions, etc?

Comment: If you're getting a 500, then you will be getting an error page sent to the browser. You can see it in Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools. What does it say?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for that, i did not know i could go an find the "hidden" 500 error. Anyway it says: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects"

Comment: put your code in try except..catch the unhandled exception and post the traceback

Comment: So it appears that I added a bug with the print functions, while the real error is when I step into "piece.getMoveOptions(pieceColumn, pieceRow, board)" there seems to be a syntax error when evaluating one of my if statements. so the code posted is in fact irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the error is actually in your debugging code:

```
print "created the piece: " + piece
```

`piece` is an instance of Pawn, and as the error says, you can't just concatenate strings with random objects. Python is not PHP - it is strongly typed, and in order to do this you need to convert the instance to its string representation. The best way to do this is to use string formatting

```
print "created the piece: %s" % piece
```

which will call the object's `__unicode__` method to convert it to a string.

Note that you should really be using logging calls rather than prints - apart from anything else, if you accidentally leave a print statement in your code when you deploy, everything will break. So it should really be:

```
logging.info('created the piece: %s', piece)
```

(logging calls take the arguments and do the string interpolation themselves, so you don't need to use the `%` operator as with print).

Comment: yes this was my error, I made __str__ methods for all of my piece objects and assumed it would be called automatically like in Java. However "pieceRow = request.POST.get("row")" as well as "pieceColumn = request.POST.get("column")" should have been converted to an int and this is what was causing my problem further down the line. Thank you so much for your help =D

Comment: when one's errors are this trivial yet one cannot figure out what is going wrong, it is a clear sign that one has been coding for too many hours in a row! =P